# jquery window.resize not working in firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, cross-browser

JQuery `window.resize()` function is working fine with chrome but its not working in `Firefox and IE`. I Don't know whats the issue. I am using `Firefox 11.0` and `IE 10`. Moreover on calling alert in `window.resize()` function Firefox ends up in a black screen window. Please help me if somebody knows the solution.

Code->

```
function setContainerLayout()                     
{              
     var body_width=$("body").width();             
     var container_width=$("#container").width();              
     var margin=(body_width-container_width)/2;             
     if(margin>0)            
     $("#container").css({"left":margin+"px"});          
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 

            setContainerLayout();

            $(window).resize(function(){
            setContainerLayout();            
           });
});
```

Comment: You should use `$(window).on("resize", function() {})`. Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: You should use `#container { margin: 0 auto; }` in your CSS to do this instead. No need for jQuery.

Comment: Tested in FF, seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/8877s/1/).

Comment: Just tested in both chrome and FF. No problem anywhere : http://jsbin.com/iwajImI/1/edit